# Netbeans Platform Installer I18N

Tags: netbeans, internationalization

When downloading the Netbeans IDE (7.3/7.4), the choice of official languages is severely crippled. Furthermore, it appears that community translations are no longer available at all.

In particular, I am interested to know if it is possible to create a Netbeans platform installer that is multi-lingual. Currently, it seems that the generated installers are always only in English (or any of the languages one downloaded the IDE for).

In case, that there is no "official" way to do this - is there another way to create the installer for a target language, or has Oracle effectively killed Netbeans RCP products?